# missing folder in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Using azure to host a dev site. The file shows up in the server files when I access through kudu. I do not see the folder listed in the source tab in chrome though. Three font files are throwing net::ERR_ABORTED

http://sg-1.azurewebsites.net/fonts/SegoeUI/latest.woff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I seem to remember having to add `woff` and `woff2` to my web.config file to permit them to be served:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The remove lines are there in case you ever run on a manually configured server. It can fail if you try to add a file extension that is already registered, so you remove and then add to be safe.

Comment: That is correct. I didn't remove the extension before adding it.